# JSON object undefined in IE11 and Tomcat 7

Tags: javascript, json, tomcat, undefined

I'm experiencing a bizarre issue and thought I'd ask for help.
I wrote an application that runs on Tomcat and uses AJAX to communicate with the server. The server returns a JSON string to the client and in my Javascript I use JSON.parse(returnedString) to generate the object from which I then get data.

The bizarre thing is that everything works on my laptop. However, when I publish the system to the QA server I get a JSON object underfined in the IE11 debugger. I use the exact same browser whether running on my laptop or off of my QA server. And JSON object is there when I run from my laptop and is undefined when I run from the QA server.

Anyone has any ideas? I'm running Tomcat 7 on my QA and Tomcat 8 on my laptop.

TIA

Comment: Is it working with a different browser, e.g. up-to-date Chrome?

Comment: Yes it works with Chrome and Firefox. Not sure about IE12 and later.